# How do I create two complementary characters, like a villain and a hero, that are designed for each other?

Tags: character-development

I'm building a D&D campaign and I'm at the point where I have to create a villain. There's also a character that will join the players a few times as a hero. In an attempt to make them more memorable, I'd like the villain and the hero to feel like they were made for one another. What makes two characters, like a hero and a villain, feel made for one another? I'm not sure I can really describe what I mean by made for one another, but I want to avoid putting just any old hero against any old villain. Simply mushing backstories together isn't quite right either.

Alternatively, what are some other hero/villain pairs that were made for one another? I can think of Batman and the Joker as an easy example.

Comment: This might be closer to D&D advice than writing advice, but be careful not to make your villain too aligned with your hero rather than the player characters - you run the risk of leaving your players bored while your two NPCs fight one another. You might be better off creating a villain who is complementary to your players.

Comment: Unless the hero you are creating is some sort of bumbling comic relief, this whole approach is likely unlikely to be good. You may want to ask this over on the RPG stack first, to figure out how to make this a viable approach. That is very likely to constrain this question much further.

Comment: @fectin can you explain why you think this whole approach won't be good?

Comment: See eg here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137643/25662

Comment: I don't plan on having my own PC. It's an NPC with limited use who's there for story and a little combat.

Comment: @whiterook6 I'd be concerned that your NPCs will steal focus from the PCs - they're supposed to feel like heroes in their story, but another hero has just shown up and is perfectly matched against the villain. In a game, do you want to feel like Luke Skywalker fighting Darth Vader or a random Rebel soldier?

Answer (score 4):

When creating any villain, or any antagonist, it important to have some characteristic (that you want to attenuate) to be the opposite of that of the hero:

- **Unbreakable**: Someone who cannot break his bones (hero) vs a person who's bones break very easily (villain)
- **Daenerys Targaryan vs Whitewalkers** (Fire vs Ice)
- **Gone Baby Gone**: Holding a promise over doing the right thing
- **Coherence**: Blue glowsticks vs Red glowsticks
- **Batman vs Superman**: Human vs Alien, technology vs natural power
- **Neo vs Mr Smith** (man vs machine --> man-machine vs machine-man, which annihilate each other)
- **Blade Runner**: Androids must live, because they have feelings vs Androids must die because they are only robots
- ...

Having heros & villains clash on topics that are important to them, where it isn't always clear to the audience what the truth of the matter is also makes their fight more significant the audience, as they can see it going both ways, thus creating tension.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are talking about is complementarity. In more practical terms, every hero, and every villain, should have both strengths and weaknesses.

Complementarity is when the villain's strength attacks the hero's weakness, and vice versa.

The Joker is clever in ways that Batman is not. Insane in ways Batman is not. Batman is intrepid and takes risks in ways the Joker does not, he has gadgets and equipment the Joker does not, he has athletic ability the Joker does not.

In order for your villain and hero to be worthy opponents, they must both be plausibly capable of defeating the other. In order for your hero to ever be in real mortal danger, she must have a weakness that can be plausibly exploited to put her in that situation. In order for your villain to be defeated, she must also have a weakness like that.

They should not have the same strengths and weaknesses. That just turns into a slugfest. That may be entertaining, but more emotional and/or strategic wins are preferable. Superman wins against his physical match from Krypton. His match keeps outsmarting him. Superman cannot defeat him, toe to toe, punch for punch, in fact he gets his ass kicked. But eventually Superman wins by the force of his emotion, risking his life for love in a way the villain (without any love) will not. Love is the one thing Superman has that the villain does not have; Superman will take any risk, even death, to protect the people he loves.

A lot of stories rely on this altruistic unselfishness of Heroes vs complete selfishness of Villains. You don't have to do that, more complex villains can be seeking what they personally believe **really is** what is best for humanity, but they also believe humanity's situation is so far gone that violence is the only path left to achieve it.

So you can also come up with other complementary attributes. Brainiac is far smarter than Superman, but physically a weak person with few other skills.

You want villains that, if they were not harming innocents to achieve their ends, would make great partners with your hero; each being awesome at something where the other is deficient. They fit together like puzzle pieces. That is also what makes them worthy opponents.

Answer (score 2):

#### Characters are as great as the hurdle they face

A simple procedure to create matching heroes and villains:

1. define one separate strength each, e.g. hero can become invisible and the villain can spit fire;
2. give the other the weakness that would make their opponent's strength prevail, e.g. the hero is made of wood and the villain has no other senses but his eyes;
3. show how the hero's strength helps him in any other occasion, except when he faces the villain;
4. pit the hero against the villain in a context such that the hero cannot use his strength, e.g. the love interest needs to see where he is;

There you have it. First you have showed the readers that the hero is obviously strong. However, when the decisive battle comes, he cannot use his strength, instead he has to overcome his crippling weakness to defeat the strong side of the villain.

Comment: I like this! Where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Give them the same goal. In sports movies, both sides want to win the game; in romantic comedies, two suitors vie for the same would-be lover; in spy movies, everyone wants the secret MacGuffin. In *Star Wars*, the Rebels aren't just looking to destroy the Empire, and the Emperor isn't just trying to tempt Luke to the Dark Side. Rather, they are both vying for control of the galaxy.

If you identify a goal that both the hero and villain can aspire to, then you have a connection, which might then suggest other connections to you. If this is a *D&D* game, maybe they're looking for a magic artifact, possibly one that will unleash the forces of Evil on this world. One of them is looking to use it, and the other is looking to destroy it, but both of them have to *find* and *retrieve* it, first. (The reason why they want the same thing can be different, but they'll still be trying to do the same thing at some crucial moment.)

Find reasons why these two are the most likely (or only) parties who can pull off this quest, and you'll find more parallels to draw between them. Perhaps only the last scion of a noble house can touch the artifact, which makes them (a) noble, and (b) siblings. Or perhaps the key to using it is a secret that an aged wizard only imparted to his trusted apprentice, but another pupil snuck into the library and discovered it. Now you have an NPC connection they both share, as well as (perhaps) a story why one was favored and the other was not.

In short, make them both part of the *same* story. Make sure they both have their proverbial Eyes on the same Prize, and the parallels and contrasts between them should start to make themselves evident.